# Primefaces SubTable within subTable

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I am trying to build a primefaces datatable which has multiple subtables.

The relationship is as below.

Supplier can have multiple Purchase Orders. Purchase Orders can have multiple Lines for the same Purchase Order.

I have following VO.

1. Supplier
2. Purchase Order Header
3. Purchase Order Lines

I have one final VO which holds List of all above VOs.

SupplierPOView

```
public List<Supplier> supplier;
public List<POHeader> poHeader;
public List<POLine>   poLine;
```

I have myBatis and corresponding mapper which maps and stores the above information in List object of

```
public List<SupplierPOView> supplierPOViewList;
```

supplierPOViewList has getter and setter.

But not sure how to represent this in primefaces datatable.

I am after where Supplier is the top level then it shows the PO Header information and then the PO Line.

can you please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<p:dataGrid />` for Supplier.

Then inside `datagrid` ,use `<p:dataTable>` for PO Header information and then for PO Line

use `p:subTable` (inside the datatable).

[DataGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf)

[DataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf)

[SubTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf)